# How can I judge a torus and picture's surface is homeomophic or not?

Tags: general-topology

[image: Please see this image]

I think that image's surface is like Möbius. So not homeomorphic to sphere. How can I judge and explain about that in usual topology $\mathbb{R}^3$?

Comment: Looks like an orientable surface of genus $2$ to me.

Comment: It's important not to get confused with how a surface is embedded iin R^3 and its homeomorphism type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you cut along the marked green curve, reposition the surface some, and then reglue, you can see that it is exactly a genus two surface.

[image]

Comment: nice pictures! :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer and picture. :)